# Can this patent on fecal transplant be granted?

Tags: patentability, international

In reference to the patent: [WO 2014/121298 A2](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2014121298A2)

This is a treatment method in human medicine and thus a patent could not be granted - at least here in Sweden. Correct?

The effects of bacterial populations are described in several earlier publications. There exist many publications about the idea of "feces transplantation". This is an observation/description of nature and not an invention. Correct?